# React js: How to Get Automatically Logout After Session Expired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-cookies

I am trying to implement automatic logout after session expired but i can't able to do it i tried to implement timeout and also cookies expire time but it did not work here is my all code. this is api for login `https://digitalfleet.eu/api/1/oauth/token/`,
I am trying to implement automatic logout after session expired but i can't able to do it i tried to implement timeout and also cookies expire time but it did not work here is my all code. this is api for login `https://digitalfleet.eu/api/1/oauth/token/`,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.redirect();
  }

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");
    axios({
      // Define Method
      method: "post",

      // Set Access Token URL
      url: config.apiUrl.login,

      //Set Headers
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(authToken)
      },

      // Interpolate variables in the strings using Template Literals
      data: `grant_type=${GRANT_TYPE}&username=${this.state.username}&password=${this.state.password}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}`
    })
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data);

        // Save All Data in localstorage
        var ls = require("local-storage");
        this.cookies = new Cookies();
        ls.set("Token", response.data["access_token"]);
        this.cookies.set("Token", response.data["access_token"], {
          path: "/",
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2592000)
        });
        ls.set("RefreshToken", response.data["refresh_token"]);
        ls.set("Toke Type", response.data["token_type"]);
        ls.set("Token Scope", response.data["scope"]);
        ls.set("Expire in", response.data["expires_in"]);

        // Used swal alert
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Log in",
          type: "success",
          text: "You Successfully loggedin",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          timer: 3000
        });
        this.redirect();
      })
      .catch(response => {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Login Error",
          type: "error",
          text: "Please Enter Correct Username and Password",
          timerProgressBar: true,
          timer: 3000
        });
      });
  }
  redirect() {
    if (ls.get("Token")) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

and here is logout code

```
onLogout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    // window.localStorage.clear();
    this.props.history.push("/");
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you should clear local storage and redirect to auth page after you will get `401 Unauthorized`

Answer (score 0):

In `this.redirect()` you are checking the token in `LocalStorage`, but you have set the expire time for the token in cookies (not in local storage )

Also, it's not possible to set expiration in local storage. Use cookies directly or control the local storage data with a service like [lscache](https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache#lscache)